# Kantorovich problem for compact spaces and continuous cost function

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, optimal-transport

I want to prove the existence of a solution to a special case of the [Kantorovich problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transportation_theory_(mathematics)#Monge_and_Kantorovich_formulations):

Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ be compact probability spaces, i.e. $X$ and $Y$ are compact metric spaces and $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures on the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra. Let $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb R$ be continuous.

We define $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ to be the set of probability measures $\gamma$ on $X\times Y$ such that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are the push forward measures of $\gamma$ with respect to the projection on $X$ and $Y$, respectively: $(\pi_x)_{\#}\gamma=\mu$ and $(\pi_y)_{\#}\gamma=\nu$.

Then the optimality problem (Kantorovich problem)
$$\mathrm{(KP)} \quad \inf_{\gamma \in \Pi(\mu,\nu)}
K(\gamma) := \int_{X\times Y} f\, \mathrm d\gamma $$
has a solution.

By Weierstrass' criterion I need to show that $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is compact and that $K$ defined above is lower semi-continuous. Considering as mode of convergence the weak convergence of probability measures, then the continuity of $K$ follows immediately because $f$ is continuous and $C(X\times Y)=C_b(X\times Y)$ in this case.

But what about the compactness of $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$?

The weak convergence encourages to work with sequence compactness. So let $(\gamma_n)$ be a sequence in $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$. If the sequence converges weakly to some probability measure $\gamma$ on $X\times Y$, I can show that $\gamma\in \Pi(\mu,\nu)$:
Let $g\in C(X)=C_b(X)$, then $(x,y)\mapsto g(x)$ is continuous (and bounded) and thus
\begin{align}
\int_X g(x) \, \mathrm d (\pi_x)_{\#}\gamma(x)
&= \int_{X\times Y} g \circ \pi_x (x,y) \, \mathrm d \gamma(x,y) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{X\times Y} g \circ \pi_x (x,y) \, \mathrm d \gamma_n(x,y) \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_X g(x) \, \mathrm d (\pi_x)_{\#}\gamma_n(x) \\
&= \int_X g(x) \, \mathrm d \mu(x)
\end{align}
where I used weak convergence and change-of-variables. For $\nu$ it is the same, obviously.

All would be well, but how do I come up with the weak limit $\gamma$? This is my question.

In the proof for the general Kantovorich problem (where $X$ and $Y$ are not compact, but merely polish and $f$ lower semi-continuous) the sequence is derived by tightness of $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ and employing Prokhorov's theorem. Here I'm looking for another way.

Comment: It is not hard to show $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is closed in the space of all probability measures on $X\times Y$. This means you are essentially looking for a proof that the space of probability measures on a compact metric space is compact. There are several ways; for example you can use  the Riesz representation theorem and the Banach–Alaoglu theorem.

Comment: Does not what I already did up there show that $\Pi(\mu,\nu)$ is closed? I only know the Riesz representation theorem from the context of Hilbert spaces. But I assume you are referring to some one-to-one relation between the space of probability measures (say $\cal P$) and a subspace in the dual of $C_b$? This should be the space of positive functionals with norm equal to $1$, right? Banach-Alaoglu states that the unit ball in $(C_b)'$ is compact with respect to the weak* topology which in this case coincides with the topology of weak convergence on $\cal P$.

Comment: Continuing: So we can associate to each $\gamma_n$ an unique element, say $\phi_n$, in $(C_b)'$ and since the $\gamma_n$ are probability measures, the $\phi_n$ will be in the $(C_b)'$ unit ball and hence have a weak*-convergent subsequence which again induces a weakly convergent subsequence $\gamma_{n_k}$. Did I omit some necessary assumption?

Comment: That is it, pretty much.